# Django TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: python, django

I build a django project named "mysite". My urls.py is

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from .views import WelcomeView
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', WelcomeView.as_view(), name='welcome'),
)
```

And my views.py is :

```
from django.views import generic
class WelcomeView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'templates/welcome.html'
```

The directory structure is

```
+/home/mysite
    - manage.py
    - static
    + mysite
        - views.py
        - urls.py
        - settings.py
        - __init__.py
        + templates
            - welcome.html
```

When I run :

```
python manage.py runserver
```

My brower says: " TemplateDoesNotExist at templates/welcome.html ". Could somesone help me ? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you have put `mysite` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`,

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'mysite',
    # ...... the rest of installed apps
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a beginner myself but I've had such issues with template does not exist. I just found tonight that it was confusing in hindsight where you put the template directory from tutorials. Even though you put an absolute path to your template directory under your project directory, I found if you create the directory under your "app" directory the templates worked.
In your question I can see:
1. You've created the project, e.g.

```
`django-admin.py startproject <app name of your choice>`
```

BUT
2. You've not created an app yet, e.g. `cd <directory of choice>`

```
django-admin.py startapp <app name of your choice>
```

Try creating the app first then putting the templates in there...

Comment: I think `app name` is the `project name`.

Comment: - Mine worked when i had it like this:   
-    mysite/ -Project  
-     manage.py  
-     myapplication - Application  
-         templates (THIS WORKED FOR ME)
-     mysite/ (The inner mysite/ directory is the actual Python package for your project. Its name is the Python package name you’ll need to use to import anything inside it (e.g. mysite.urls).)  
-         __init__.py  
-         settings.py  
-         urls.py  
-         wsgi.py  
-         templates (where I thought the templates would work but didn't for me, originally my settings.py file had this absolute path references too.)